# How to do a reversible migration for add_column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, reverse, rollback, rails-migrations

This migration works perfectly

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :title, limit: 500, null: false
    end    
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        add_column :users, :courses_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
      end
      dir.down do
        remove_column :users, :courses_count
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run this it adds courses_count but it does *not* remove it on `rails db:rollback`. Isn't the point of reversible migrations with the `def change` method that it would reverse `add_column`?

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string :title, limit: 500, null: false
     
      add_column :users, :courses_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
    end    
  end
end

% rails db:migrate
== 20200815181736 CreateCourses: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:courses)
-- add_column(:users, :courses_count, :integer)
   -> 0.0037s
   -> 0.0258s
== 20200815181736 CreateCourses: migrated (0.0259s) ===========================

% rails db:rollback
== 20200815181736 CreateCourses: reverting ====================================
-- drop_table(:courses)
   -> 0.0060s
== 20200815181736 CreateCourses: reverted (0.0078s) ===========================

% rails db:migrate 
== 20200815181736 CreateCourses: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:courses)
-- add_column(:users, :courses_count, :integer)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::DuplicateColumn: ERROR:  column "courses_count" of relation "users" already exists
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`add_column` [needs to be outside](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#using-the-change-method) the `create_table` block

```
def change
  create_table :courses do |t|
    t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
    t.string :title, limit: 500, null: false   
  end    

  add_column :users, :courses_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
end
```